# Google APIs Batch Requests returning 411 Length-Required Error

Tags: flutter, dart, gmail, gmail-api

I'm attempting to make a batch request to the Gmail API, as outlined here: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/batch

I've got to the point at which I have the URL, headers, and body of my request, and the headers include an (accurate) `Content-Length` attribute. However, when I make the `POST` request to the Gmail batch request endpoint, the response is a [411 Length-Required][1] response, returning in the body an HTML document stating:

```
411. That’s an error.

POST requests require a Content-length header. That’s all we know.
```

My code looks something like the following:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'package:googleapis/gmail/v1.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class GoogleClient {
  static const _SCOPES = const [GmailApi.GmailReadonlyScope];
  static GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(scopes: _SCOPES);
  static String _gmailUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/';
  static String _batchGmailUrl = 'https://www.googleapis.com/batch/gmail/v1';
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  GoogleSignInAccount _user;

  Future<List<Message>> fetchEmailsBatch({List<String> gmailMessageIds}) async {
    await _ensureUserIsAuthenticated();

    final boundary = 'batch_email';

    var body = '--' + boundary + '\r\n';

    for (String id in gmailMessageIds) {
      final messageUrl = '/gmail/v1/users/' + _user.email + '/messages/' + id;

      body += 'Content-Type: application/http\r\n';
      body += 'Content-ID: email:' + id + '\r\n\r\n';
      body += 'GET ' + messageUrl + '\r\n\r\n';
      body += '--' + boundary + '\r\n';
    }

    final bodyAsBytes = utf8.encode(body);
    final headers = await _batchAuthHeaders(bodyAsBytes.length);

    final response = await http.post(_batchGmailUrl,
        headers: await _batchAuthHeaders(bodyAsBytes.length),
        body: bodyAsBytes);
  }

  Future<Map<String, String>> _batchAuthHeaders(int length) async {
    var headers = await _user.authHeaders;

    headers[HttpHeaders.contentLengthHeader] = length.toString();
    headers[HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader] =
        'multipart/mixed; boundary=batch_email';
    headers[HttpHeaders.hostHeader] = 'www.googleapis.com';

    return headers;
  }

  Future<void> _ensureUserIsAuthenticated() async {
    if (_user == null) {
      await signIn();
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, all of the sub-requests being made in the body of the batch request are `GET` requests, and therefore are not covered by the error message I'm receiving. I can't seem to find any more expansive documentation that that already linked above, nor any other similar issues already reported on GitHub or StackOverflow.

Any help would be greatly appreciated - thanks in advance!

[1]: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/411#:~:text=The%20HyperText%20Transfer%20Protocol%20(HTTP,a%20defined%20Content%2DLength%20header.

Comment: Does it work if you skip the batching?  Why are you bothering with batching?

Comment: Hey there @PeterJohnstone, can you please provide more information on what are you trying to achieve with the batch request you are making? Also, on the `final respone` you are using `http.post`.

Comment: Hey @DaImTo, I'm trying to batch requests so I can retrieve emails from a given sender in as few requests as possible, otherwise I'd have to make ~50 or so requests in parallel and handle each response, which compromises the performance of my app. It's not that it's unusable without the batching, but it makes a big difference to the end-user experience to batch these requests

Comment: @ale13 Yup, I'm using a post request deliberately, such is understanding from the docs for the Gmail API: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/batch#example But perhaps I'm wrong on needing to use a POST request there?

As to what I'm trying to achieve, my app needs to fetch a bunch of data from the Gmail API on opening, from several different emails, and I'd like to keep network calls to a minimum - making a single batch request for example, rather than (at the moment) around 50 or so individual requests

Comment: @ale13 I think a POST request **is** required here, as the docs I linked just above state:
```
Note: The batch system for the Gmail API uses the same syntax as the OData batch processing system, but the semantics differ.
```

And link to https://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/batch-processing/

This states: 
```
Finally, batch requests MUST NOT include an X-HTTP-Method header (i.e. use POST tunelling) as batch requests are by definition POST only.
```

Comment: @PeterJohnstone, I understand now, my bad! Maybe in this situation, can you share how your headers look like? Moreover, do they have any newline characters?

Comment: @ale13 No worries at all - thanks for your help! 

And sure thing - my headers in the request at the moment are: `{ Authorization: Bearer foobar, X-Goog-AuthUser: 0, content-length: 323, content-type: multipart/mixed; boundary=batch_email, host: www.googleapis.com }`. I've printed these out from inside the `base_client.dart` file inside of the Dart http package (https://pub.dev/packages/http), so I'm pretty sure that there's not anything weird going on with the package stripping them out or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a reported bug in Flutter that has been fixed since. As of writing this, it's not yet visible in a release but it will appear soon, hopefully.

As a temporary workaround, you can use the lower level `dart:io` calls instead.

Comment: I've just received it myself with the latest beta and was able to remove the workaround. I don't know about the stable branch.